# Get vis.js networkEvents from the controller

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

I need to use click event in my controller.
The networkEvents are created in angular-vs.js directive and I need it in my controller to trigger the click event of individual nodes.

This is a code snippet I'm using but it does seem to work:

```
$scope.networkEvents = { onload:function(network){ alert("Clicked"); } }
```

Thanks,

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N639ZxuIjvTO1MidM2D2?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## index.html

It looks like you don't set your events attribute of the vis-network directive, so I think you meant:

```
<vis-network data="data" options="options" events="networkEvents" height="100%"></vis-network>
```

## angular-vis.js

Also, in the onload callback of the vis-network directive (line 151) you're passing graph into the onload function, but it isn't defined. (Maybe it's supposed to be network instead?):

```
// onLoad callback
if (scope.events != null && scope.events.onload != null &&
    angular.isFunction(scope.events.onload)) {
    scope.events.onload(network);
}
```

## script.js

With the above changes, the onload function seems to work as expected. Since you've already set up the forEach loop to attach the events, to get the click event you just need to add it to the networkEvents object:

```
$scope.networkEvents = 
{
    onload: function(network){
        alert("I'm loaded");
    },
    click: function(clicked) {
        alert("id: " + clicked.nodes[0] + " was clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: @lcywizard00 Thanks a lot it just worked like a charm